# How to connect to Exchange 2013 from Outlook Mobile?

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013

I'm on an Android device (8.0) with the current Outlook Mobile.  I'm unable to connect to my Exchange 2013 server as it throws a generic login failure.  Oddly, I *am* able to connect fine with AndroidMail.

I did a

> Get-MobileDevice -Mailbox me | fl FriendlName,Device*,Client*,Is*

and found that for unknown reasons it was blocked for Outlook Mobile on my current device ID (but allowed for devices I no longer have).  I then did a

> Set-CASMailbox -Identity:"me"
>   -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs:"hexdeviceID"

My device now shows up as allowed with the Outlook Mobile string, but still will not function.  Same exact login failure.  I've reviewed the Exchange IIS logs and I see the pings.  Everything appears to be successful (but I'm not skilled at reading Exchange logs).  Anything in particular I should look for in Exchange?

Comment: Does the activesync feature enable for the mailbox？If has enabled, please check the appiled mobile device mailbox policy, if everything is correct, after allowing the device id, we can wait for hours and check if any helps. Details about mobile device policy see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/exchange-activesync/mobile-device-mailbox-policies

Comment: @Niko.Cheng It is ActiveSync enabled.  Everything in the policy appears correct.  Still does not work days later after my device ID unblock.  Seems like it may be global in nature as nobody else I've talked to here can use Outlook either (but they are able to use all kinds of 3rd party clients).  The users I've checked don't have the block to begin with.  I have no idea how mine ended up with a device ID block. Anyways, doesn't work for anyone which is very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that Outlook Mobile only functions with cloud hosted e-mail.  I've never been able to get it to work for any of our on-prem hosted accounts.  However, as soon as I migrate an account to the cloud it will start working with Outlook Mobile.